# Cannot increase xdebug.max_nesting_level (php.ini)

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug, ini

I have the following error

```
Maximum function nesting level of '120' reached, aborting!
```

Therefore I tried to increase the max nesting level by putting this in my php.ini

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
```

I also added the following to my application

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);
```

However, I still receive the exact same error with the 120 - so it doesn't change the max. amount.

Comment: did you restart the server after making those changes?

Comment: yes - multiple times until now, I somehow managed to get it working when placing the ini_set directly in the function where it always failed. But I'm still not sure why it didn't work when changing the config file